# how do i get this object to follow a specific bone?

Tags: modifiers, bones, transforms, constraints

I am trying to get this model to follow a specific bone on the character's hand (the "weapon" bone) and it becomes really big when I give it an object constraint.
[image: me adding a copy transforms object constraint]
[image: the bone I need to attach it to]

how do I fix this? I plan on using it for animation.

https://mega.nz/file/v0dBAYAQ#6CIfjRybHtoOcapTpVaYge_V9BgqhSPiEPEjnuhHSbU

fairly new to asking pros about small problems so tell me if I need to give more info.

Comment: Your uploaded blend file doesn't have the object constraint as shown in the screen shot, so I'm not sure what you did. Try using the *child* *of* constraint for your weapon.

Comment: in the first image, look at the bottom right area to see the object constraint i added to the gun. also i cont figure out what the child of the constraint is.

Comment: just figured out what you mean by child of constraint. i had to move it around a little but it ended up working in the end. thanks

Comment: ok i was told by the person who commented that I needed to add the "child of" constraint instead of copy transforms